# How to call a third party composer app in a Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I try to work with "https://github.com/FragLand/minestat", and tried to get the server status.

But I get the error: Class "MineStat" not found, so **how do I work exactly with third party components and add them to codeigniter so that I can use them in a controller
**

I tried to add the line

`use MineStat;`

and then I tried to work with it, so I created a function.

```
public function getServerStatus($ip) {
        $ms = new MineStat($ip);
        return $ms->is_online();
    }
```

Comment: How did you install that "third party composer app"?

Comment: If you are using the code from https://github.com/FragLand/minestat_package: the example there includes the class directly, as there is no proper autoloader configuration